# mootools - request json with freegeoip

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

I am trying to display city and region data in a html element using JSON feed from freegeoip.net. I am pretty new to Mootools and I am not sure where I am going wrong with my current script.

My current script is https://jsfiddle.net/uv1qu25r/5/

```js
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
  url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
  function(data) {
    $('city1').set('text', data.city);
    $('region').set('text', data.region_name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.js"></script>
Your City is <span id="city1"></span><br> Your Region is <span id="region"></span>
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Not really related to the question, is there a reason using Mootools over jQuery? I have just skimmed through their docs and it looks like jQuery.

Comment: The project I am working with has been coded up using Mootools, I can actually do it in jquery but don't have that choice here.

Answer (score 0):

The MooTools API needs a `.send()` method to be called. You need to pass also the `onSuccess` and not just a function if I remember correct.

Try:

```
new Request.JSON({
  url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
  onSuccess: function(data) {
    $('city1').set('text', data.city);
    $('region').set('text', data.region_name);
  }
}).send();
```

Note: that URL does not seem to allow CORS, so that might be a separated problem to tackle...

Comment: URL does allow CORS as I have it working with JQuery implementation. Adding a send() didnt do anything for me.

Comment: @ArifM can you share a jsFiddle with jQuery working? I'm happy to adapt to MooTools if you have it working with jQuery :)